# Trouble installing jekyll-import - Conflicting jekyll and safe_yaml versions

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion, jekyll

Despite having installed safe_yaml, installing jekyll-import fails saying that it can't be found.

```
$ gem list --local | grep safe
safe_yaml (0.9.7)
$ gem install jekyll-import --pre
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
     Unable to resolve dependencies: jekyll-import requires safe_yaml (~> 0.7.0)
$
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Giacecco

Answer (score 1):

its a version issue you will have to upgrade or downgrade safe_yaml version, As mentioned in the error it will install only on safe_yaml 0.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is the (partial) solution I have found.

Following zapbuild's advice in this thread I *also* installed safe_yaml 0.7.0, but then I crashed vs a circular reference conflict between the three gems: jekyll, jekyll-import and safe_yaml. I won't give you the detail of that.

After several attempts, the solution was to uninstall all previous jekyll and safe_yaml versions and temporarily install 1.2.1 that is the most recent to be compatible with jekyll-import's requirements while also using safe_yaml 0.7.* still.

After completing the import, I had to downgrade to jekyll 0.12.0 that is the latest Octopress' strict requirement (not even 0.12.1!).

The import was not completely successful anyway (the articles are there in the file structure but are not linked from the website structure, and the images were not fetched, despite me specifying the contrary), but the installation problem is solved.

Giacecco

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions issue. Try `sudo gem install jekyll-import --pre`